# UIcontrol push button to plot data from workspace in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, workspace, uicontrol

I'm new to matlab and I'm stuck with a callback function to plot data from the workspace. In my code pushbutton 1 and 2 allows me to import data into workspace ('importTac' and 'importref' are separate m.files to import data into workspace and they work well).

My question is how can I plot the data from the workspace through a click on pushbutton_3?

```
function KinA
%Configure window
h.fig = figure('MenuBar', 'none','units','pixels','Position', [0 0 1280 750],... % [x,y,width, height]
    'name','KinA | Kinetic Analysis','numbertitle','off','Resize', 'off');
tgroup = uitabgroup('Parent', h.fig); 

% Define tabs
tab1 = uitab('Parent', tgroup, 'Title', '1| IMPORT DATA');
tab2 = uitab('Parent', tgroup, 'Title', '2| Dynamic parameters');
tab3 = uitab('Parent', tgroup, 'Title', '3| Dynamic plots');
tab4 = uitab('Parent', tgroup, 'Title', '4| Volume of distribution, DVR');


%CONTENT ON TAB1: importdata, plot TAC and 
handles.button_1 = uicontrol('Parent', tab1, 'Style','pushbutton',...
             'String','Import TACs','Position',[20 650 120 25], 'Callback', 'importTac'); % [x,y,width, height]

handles.button_2 = uicontrol('Parent', tab1, 'Style','pushbutton',...
             'String','Import reference','Position',[20 620 120 25], 'Callback', 'importRef'); % [x,y,width, height]button_importReference = uicontrol

handles.button_3 = uicontrol('Parent',tab1, 'Style','pushbutton',...
   'String','Plot raw data','Position',[20 590 120 25], 'Callback',{@plot_data,handles});

%Define axes   
handles.ax1 = axes('Parent', tab1 , 'units', 'pixels', 'Position',[200 450 300 200]);
set(gca, 'tickdir', 'out', 'box', 'off', 'FontSize', 14 ,'Color',[0.8 0.8 0.9]);
xlabel('Time [min]', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontName', 'Arial');
ylabel('Activity [kBq]', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontName', 'Arial');


%Callback function

end
```

Comment: How `importTac` and `importRef` are defined? Do they return anything?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. importTac and importRef are defined by uigetdir and uigetfile. They work fine. 

I figured it out. I used evalin to access variables in the workspace




%Callback function TAC plot
    function plot_data(source,eventdata)
             
     time = evalin('base','xValues');
     brain = evalin('base','y1Values');
     input = evalin('base','y2Values');

          p1=plot(handles.ax1,time,brain)
          p2=plot(handles.ax2,time,input)
end

Answer (score 0):

%evalin() to access variables in the workspace
%Callback function

```
function plot_data(source,eventdata) 
time = evalin('base','xValues'); 
brain = evalin('base','y1Values'); 
input = evalin('base','y2Values'); 
p1=plot(handles.ax1,time,brain); 
p2=plot(handles.ax2,time,input);
end
```